# Does $1-ab\geq (1-a)(1-b)$ hold, for $a,b\in [0,1]$?

Tags: inequality

Does this inequality hold, for any $a,b\in[0,1]$

$$1-ab\geq (1-a)(1-b)?$$

I'm don't have idea to conclude $1-ab\geq 1-a-b+ab = (1-a)(1-b)$.

Anyone can prove (or disprove) it?

Comment: Should the inequality be the opposite? The current fails f.e. $a=b=0.5$. But numerically the opposite seems to be true.

Comment: Sorry, I'm typo. The symbol is $\geq$ instead of $\leq$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Take $a=0$ and $b=1$ to disprove it.

**Addendum:**

Now that you changed the inequality, it follows from [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means):

$a+b\ge2\sqrt a\sqrt b\ge 2ab\iff 1-ab\ge1+ab-a-b=(1-a)(1-b)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm typo. The inequality is using $\geq$ instead of $\leq$.

Comment: how is $a+b\ge 2ab$ AM-GM!

Comment: good point, @AlbusDumbledore; I edited

Comment: @J.W.Tanner no problem you are still missing a $2$!(typo)

Comment: good point again, @AlbusDumbledore; I edited again

Comment: @J.W.Tanner now its nice! i had already upvoted

Comment: Thanks for your help; I should get some sleep; I like your answer too $(+1)$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

as $1-a\ge 0,1-b\ge 0$
$$1-ab-(1-a)(1-b)=a(1-b)+b(1-a)\ge 0$$

Answer (score 3):

I approached this question geometrically.

[Desmos for fun](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/izhidwlrhn)

Start with a square of side length 1. Divide the square along one side in the ratio $a:(1-a)$, and the other side $b:(1-b)$. By considering the relevant areas given by $(1-ab)$ and $(1-a)(1-b)$, it should be obvious the inequality is true.

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{RHS} - \text{LHS} = 1+ab -a-b - (1-ab) = 2ab-a-b ≤ 2ab-a^2 - b^2 = -(a-b)^2 ≤ 0.  $$
Thus $\text{LHS} \ge \text{RHS}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $m=2a-1$ i.e. $m\in [-1 , 1]$ and $n=b-\frac{1}{2}$ i.e. $n\in [-\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}]$. Is the following true?

$$
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2}&\leq mn\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
-ab&\leq (1-a)(1-b)\leq 1-ab
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$1-ab \ge 1-a \ge (1-a)(1-b).\blacksquare$

---

Update: I found this is equivalent to that of [@Albus Dumbledore](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/769226/albus-dumbledore) and [@Tony Ip](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/855706/tony-ip).